# What is the best way in Oracle query, to avoid updating a field , if that is unchanged?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I just wanted to know the best way I can use in Oracle query, to avoid updating a field , if that is unchanged?

```
Update xtab1 set xfield1='xxx' where xkey='123';
```

In performance aspect what is best way , with which this update should not be invoked , if the existing value of xfield1 is 'xxx' .

Option1 :

> - step1:Invoke a SELECT to Fetch the value of xfield1
> - step2:If the above value is not 'xxx', then only invoke UPDATE

Option2 :

> - Invoke update as below:
>
>   Update xtab1 set xfield1='xxx' where xkey='123' and xfield1 <> 'xxx'

Please let me know which of the above 2 is best and ideal way, or is there any other ideal approach to be used?

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Update xtab1 set xfield1='xxx' where xkey='123' and xfield1 <> 'xxx'

The **filter predicate** is applied before doing the update. So, I would go with option 2 and **let Oracle do the job for you rather than doing it manually to first filter out the rows**. Also, it would be an overhead to do it in two different steps. The filtering of rows should be a part of the same step.

Regarding the performance, I think **indexes** would play an important role.

You can test it and see:

**Without index**

**Option 1**

```
SQL> EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
  2  UPDATE t SET sal = 9999 WHERE deptno = 20;

Explained.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM TABLE(dbms_xplan.display);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 931696821

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | UPDATE STATEMENT   |      |     5 |    35 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  UPDATE            | T    |       |       |            |          |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| T    |     5 |    35 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - filter("DEPTNO"=20)

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

**Option 2**

```
SQL> EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
  2  UPDATE t SET sal = 9999 WHERE deptno = 20 AND sal<>9999;

Explained.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM TABLE(dbms_xplan.display);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 931696821

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | UPDATE STATEMENT   |      |     4 |    28 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  UPDATE            | T    |       |       |            |          |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| T    |     4 |    28 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - filter("DEPTNO"=20 AND "SAL"<>9999)

14 rows selected.
```

**With Index**

```
SQL> CREATE INDEX t_idx ON t(deptno,sal);

Index created.
```

**Option 1**

```
SQL> EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
  2  UPDATE t SET sal = 9999 WHERE deptno = 20;

Explained.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM TABLE(dbms_xplan.display);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1175576152

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name  | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | UPDATE STATEMENT  |       |     5 |    35 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  UPDATE           | T     |       |       |            |          |
|*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN| T_IDX |     5 |    35 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - access("DEPTNO"=20)

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

**Option 2**

```
SQL> EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
  2  UPDATE t SET sal = 9999 WHERE deptno = 20 AND sal<>9999;

Explained.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM TABLE(dbms_xplan.display);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1175576152

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name  | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | UPDATE STATEMENT  |       |     4 |    28 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  UPDATE           | T     |       |       |            |          |
|*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN| T_IDX |     4 |    28 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - access("DEPTNO"=20)
       filter("SAL"<>9999)

15 rows selected.

SQL>
```

So, in option 2 in all the cases, the **filter("SAL"<>9999)** is applied.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there will be significant performance difference between the two options, as both will require looking up rows and performing comparison of the values. And I doubt other options such as pre-update triggers will yield better performance than your option 2.

If you really wanted to know how the Oracle optimizer handles your queries, try the [`EXPLAIN PLAN` statement](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10752/ex_plan.htm). For example, to see the plan that the Oracle optimizer formulated to execute your second option, try this:

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
UPDATE xtab1 SET xfield1='xxx' 
WHERE xkey='123' AND xfield1 <> 'xxx'
```

There is more information about what the different columns of a `EXPLAIN PLAN` result means in this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/860450/1144203).

Now, if you are dealing with large number of transactions, I recommend consider other options such as comparing the values at the application level, so as to avoid expensive database I/Os all together where possible :-) or use some form of ETL tools that are optimized to handle large transactions.

Answer (score 1):

Where would you fetch the value? In some application?

I don't think there would be much difference between the two for smaller queries. For more complex ones, I would suggest to go with second choice to make Oracle optimize the query for you for best results.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all.

I have chosen to go with the Option 2, even my DBA agrees to that as the better approach.